# Infinite Cat and One Mouse

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

These are just a series of questions/puzzles I thought of that relates to analysis and really small stuff.

Consider a unit circle, with countable point-object cats, originally located at the rationals. (As in, if there is a curve made from [0,1] to a unit circle, and the cats are located at points where the pre-image is a rational.)

The cats can only move along the circle. The circle is in an infinite plane. A point-object mouse is located in the middle of the circle.

The mouse has a higher max speed than the cats and can move in any direction. The mouse and cats both have unlimited acceleration. Both mouse and cats are perfect players. The cats are trying to catch the mouse, and the mouse is trying to escape.

Can the mouse escape the circle? I'm looking for a proof of either affirmative or negative.

Rule clarifications:

1. The cats have a hive mind/ one player is controlling all the cats.
2. The cats and mouse can see everything at the present. There is no speed of light limitations/reaction speed issues.
3. The velocity of the cat/mouse can change instantaneously. At any moment, regardless of the past, the magnitude of the velocity of the cat/mouse can be anything less or equal to the max, and the direction can be anything on the plane.
4. A cat catches a mouse if the cat and the mouse are in the same location.

Comment: I think you need to define the game better.  I don't think the infinite number of cats matters, so we can focus on just one cat, at least locally.  The mouse starts by moving very close to the circle.  What prevents a single cat from staying directly outside the mouse no matter how the mouse moves? From that point of view the mouse can never escape.

Comment: The mouse is faster than the cat.

Comment: OK then the plurality of cats matters.  They can certainly stay dense in the circle, so we still need to specify what they know about the mouse's movement.  I think the result you are looking for is that the mouse escapes with probability $1$ because there are only countably many cats and uncountably many points the mouse can pass through the circle

Comment: The cats are dense though, and they can move. They can also see the mouse, and we ignore speed of light limitations. This presumably mean that they know the location of the mouse. I think this would mean they know the velocity of the mouse as well. The cats are also a hive mind, I suppose.

Comment: Does the mouse have to move on a differentiable curve?  If not, the velocity is not well defined.  It seems simple to say both sides know the locations of the opposition at all times in the past but passing to the continuous limit seems problematic.  Certainly if you impose a time step and say each creature can move anywhere in a circle with radius its speed times the time step the mouse can escape because it never touches the circle.  If you say the cats catch the mouse if they are within $\epsilon$ they can be dense and they catch the mouse if the steps are small enough.

Comment: I think, if they have a maximum speed, they have to move on a $C^0$ curve? I think this is how it works anyways. Or maybe, for every $\epsilon \geq 0$, the cat/mouse cannot have moved more than $v\epsilon$ away in $\epsilon$ time. And to catch, I'd think they have to be in the same position.

Comment: It seems you are inventing a game or problem. But as Ross Millikan stated, ("I think you need to define the game better"), me too consider that rules are not well written. But, for your help, you can read this article "http://datagenetics.com/blog/october12013/index.html", it will clarify some concepts, and then you can modify it to your own desire.

Comment: What rules are unclear?