# Is there a strategy whereby a pigeon can escape an eagle in a sphere?

Tags: manifolds, euclidean-geometry, computer-science

This is a [pursuit-evasion problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pursuit-evasion) somewhat related to the [mice problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mice_problem), which is discussed in a few questions on here, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191654/infinite-cat-and-one-mouse). After spending a while looking through all the documentation I ran into on pursuit-evasion problems, [pursuit curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pursuit_curve), and all the related math I can find, I can't find a satisfying answer to this one, so I'm putting it to the community:

Let's say I've got a pigeon and an eagle, flying in a large sphere. The pigeon and eagle each have the same maximum speed, the same acceleration (which is also unrealistically the same regardless of direction of travel), the same (infinite) endurance, and begin traveling one after the other, the hungry eagle seeking to catch the poor pigeon.

Given these conditions, intuitively it would seem that the eagle will inevitably catch the pigeon. The pigeon will eventually reach one of the walls and have to turn, and slowly these turns will give up the distance advantage the pigeon has over the eagle, until the eagle gets his lunch. Given that a sphere does not allow for an object traveling perpendicular to its outer surface to turn 90 degrees at the "wall", because the wall is not perfectly flat, being part of the sphere, every turn at 90 degrees will involve turning onto a new vector at least slightly opposite the last, therefore giving up on distance. Perhaps by turning early, or by avoiding flying into the wall at 90 degrees, the pigeon can avoid this distance loss, and evade the eagle indefinitely.

While it seems quite clear that the pigeon could never gain distance on the eagle, is there a strategy by which the pigeon can avoid the eagle forever?

Comment: Humans really hate pigeons lol.